# Creating service instance using nestJS DI - not for web request

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs, nestjs-config

I have two problems using nestJs DI (and unfortunately the documentations are all the same and contains only basic usage information about the topics):

- what if I construct an AppModule, and simple I need to **create a service** just in case (currently my rabbitMq handler - served in moleculer - needs a document service instance)
- what if the document service instance (for rabbitMq) **depends on a user instance**, which is a dependency for the document service, and in this case the user must be created (injected) in a different way than as usual (when it is used for serving a web request)?

```javascript
@Injectable()
class DocumentService {
    @Inject('USER') user: IUser;
    @Inject() protected userRepository: UserRepository;
    @Inject() protected documentRepository: DocumentRepository;

    public void saveDocument() {
        ...
    } 
}
```

where

```javascript
@Module({
    controllers: [DocumentController]
    providers: [
        // repositories
        UserRepository, DocumentRepository, 
        // services
        DocumentService,
        // user
            {
                provide: 'USER',
                scope: Scope.REQUEST,
                useFactory: (req:Request) => req["user"] ?? null,
            },
        ],
    exports: ['USER'],
})


export class AppModule {}
```

What I should use is a code like this:

```
let rabbitMqUser = new user('rabbitMqServiceUser');
// change the IUser not come from request but use this instance for now:
// but use the DI injections describe above for the 'default' web request case
let documentService = pleaseNestJsConstructForMe<DocumentService>(where 'USER'=rabbitMqUser);
```

Comment: Where is your rabbitMq logic located, is it not a part of NestJS module?

Comment: No, its not. It is handled by moleculer, separate port, separate everything. All is shared the services between the nestJS web service and the rabbitMq service handler.

Comment: If you want to have NestJS instantiate and inject an object for you as per your request `pleaseNestJsConstructForMe`, then it must be registered in a NestJS module list of providers.